# $GLOBALS not visible inside another php file

Tags: php, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to use $GLOBALS to define an international dictionary for my application. The strings are in different files, one for each language. Like this:

```
PT_BR.txt:
title=Meu aplicativo
usr=Usuário

EN_US.txt:
title=My app
usr=User
```

Then I have one function to read the txt file and fill the $GLOBALS array, and other to get a value from the $GLOBALS and return it to the script. Both are in functions.php, which is included in every necessary file.

```
// functions.php
function readDict($lang) {
    $F = $lang.'.txt';
    // (...)
    $GLOBALS[$var] = $val;
}
function txt($line) {
    if (isset($GLOBALS[$line])) {
        return $GLOBALS[$line];
    } else {
        return "($line)";
    }
}
```

I call the first function in main.php, when the user chooses a language:

```
readDict($language);
```

When I call txt('some_variable') from main.php, it works ok. But when I call it from another file, it doesn't. For instance, when I call

```
include('functions.php');
echo txt('esp.col');
```

from addEsp.php, it can't see the $GLOBALS['esp.col'], which works in main.php. Why?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `readDict($language)` in your second snippet (after the `include`) is that a typo or a bug?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to read the dictionary from the file only once, put those values into the $GLOBALS array, and then get them from there. If I was to read from the files every time the user opens a page, I wouldn't need to use a global variable at all (and I think reading many times from memory is more efficient than reading from disk).

Comment: Yes but your second code snippet is reading the dictionary 0 times.

Comment: Yes, that's why I want the values from the dictionary become transfered to the $GLOBALS variable. And I want that to be done once per session (when the user logs in, or when he/she changes the language), not in every page access.

Comment: Use $_SESSION instead of $GLOBALS. As far as I know globals are only valid until the end of the current request.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$GLOBALS = [];
function readDict($lang) {
    $F = $lang.'.txt';
    // (...)
    $GLOBALS[$var] = $val;
}
function txt($line) {
    if (isset($GLOBALS[$line])) {
        return $GLOBALS[$line];
    } else {
        return "($line)";
    }
}
```

You can try this

Comment: But if I do $GLOBALS = []; inside functions.php, won't it be reseted every time function.php is included elsewhere?